# \tableofcontents in twocolum document

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, two-column

I don't quite understand why `\tableofcontents` in a `\twocolumn` document yields only one column (or how to change that - ideally *without* including `multicol` just for the ToC...)?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}  % twocolumn set document-wide...
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents                    % ...but not working for the ToC?
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Baz}
\lipsum[3]
\section{FooBarBaz}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you're using a `KOMA-script` class, use `\unsettoc` from the `tocbasic` package. See chapter 13 of the `KOMA-script` manual for details.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}
\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Baz}
\lipsum[3]
\section{FooBarBaz}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: "Every good solution is obvious once you've found it." Thanks.