# KOMA-Script (scrbook): onecolumn table of contents & minitoc in twocolumn document

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, two-column, minitoc, scrbook

I have problem with formatting of my tables of contents. Please see my MNWE below. I would like to *switch all of my tables into one column layout*. I try to use solution from this [tex.stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25750/tableofcontents-in-twocolum-document/25752#25752), which use this peace of the tex code:

```
\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}
```

but it seems, that doesn't work. I tried to understand manual scrbook (page [264](http://www.komascript.de/files/scrguien.pdf)), but unfortunately I did not get it. I use miktex/xelatex. I attach also pictures the result of translation.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}  
\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\minitoc
\lipsum[1]
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Baz}
\lipsum[3]
\section{FooBarBaz}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]
 **figure 1**: Command `\tableofcontents`

---

[image]
 **figure 2**: Command `\minitoc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### For the main toc

Please read carefully again the linked answer and the KOMA-Script documentation<sup>1)</sup>: **By default** in `scrbook` (and `scrreprt`) the toc is set in *onecolumn modus*. Only, when you want to have it in two columns, you need `\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}`. So, leaving it out is the solution here …

#### For the minitoc

Use `\setchapterpreamble`<sup>2)</sup>. Note, you must set it before the chapter, where it belongs to. With two optional arguments you can influence position and width.

Also take notice, that I had to deactivate the rules before and after with `\mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off}`. As workaround I added two times `\hrulefill` (the first must be in `\smash` and then a make box [it would have worked without, but then a more difficult vertical space determining], the second would also work without, but I just copied it) and some vertical spaces. I guess, the `\vspace` must be individually adjusted to one’s font and font size.

Since you very probably will have more than one chapter, I defined two new commands, see below code for remarks. Because these have `\setchapterpreamble` inside (or are intended to use them inside), *these* must be set before each chapter.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}
\mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\dochaptertoc}{%
  \vspace{1.85\baselineskip} % workaround for removed rule
  \smash{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill}} % workaround for removed rule
  \vspace{-1.85\baselineskip} % workaround for removed rule
  \minitoc
  \vspace{-1.15\baselineskip} % workaround for removed rule
  \smash{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill}} % workaround for removed rule
  \vspace{1.15\baselineskip} % workaround for removed rule
}
\newcommand{\setchaptertoc}{%
  \setchapterpreamble{% KOMA-Script command
    \dochaptertoc%
  }}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\setchaptertoc
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{One, one}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{One, one, one}
\lipsum[3]
\section{One, two}
\lipsum[4]

\setchapterpreamble{
  \dictum{Time for a bon-mot.}% KOMA-Script command
  \dochaptertoc
}
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Two, one}
\lipsum[6]
\section{Two, two}
\subsection{two, two, one}
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

In most cases it will be enough to put `\setchaptertoc` in front of a chapter. But for cases, when you want to add more than the minitoc, I defined `\dochaptertoc` with the workarounds for removed rules intended for use in `\setchapterpreamble`, cf. chapter 2 in the example.

<sup>1)</sup> Read online on Texdoc.net: [“\setuptoc” & “\unsettoc”](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf#tocbasic.cmd.unsettoc) (PDF)

<sup>2)</sup> Read online on Texdoc.net, as well: [“\setpartpreamble” & “\setchapterpreamble”](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf#maincls.cmd.setchapterpreamble) (PDF again)

Comment: OK. '\unsettoc{toc}{twocolumn}' is right way for main TOC. But for TOC per chapter (command '\minitoc') is still formatted in twocolumn layout.

Comment: Jafan, you can simply leave `\unsettoc{toc}…` out, then the default is used. For the minitoc: Yes, I've overseen this, but it would have been better from you, to write more elaborate about your problem. Answer edited.