# scrwfile removes partial Toc created with titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using `titletoc` to create a partial toc at the beginning of each `\part`.

Now I introduced the package `scrwfile` to get more `\write` outputs. 
This however also removes the partial toc.

Is there a way to get it back using titletoc? Otherwise I would be interested in an alternative.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrwfile}
\usepackage{titletoc}   

\newcommand{\PartialToc}[1]{%
    \startcontents[part]
    \section*{\contentsname}
    \printcontents[part]{}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\tableofcontents

\part{Part Heading First}
\PartialToc{1}
\chapter{first}
\chapter{second}
\stopcontents[part]

\part{Part Heading Second}
\PartialToc{1}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\stopcontents[part]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider filing a bug to Markus Kohm. There is a file `komabug.tex` in the `doc` subtree for KOMA-Script. As alternative you could take a look on `minitoc`, loosely related to this is [KOMA-Script (scrbook): onecolumn table of contents & minitoc in twocolumn document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151320/).

Comment: Markus Kohm responded to my request by saying that both packages are incompatible by design (both redefine `\@writefile`)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say anything about the issue between `scrwfile` and `titletoc` other than Markus Kohm back in past frequently uttered about possible incompatibilities with such programs, that change KOMA-script class commands. I actually do not know, whether it is the case here. Regarding to `titletoc`’s “sister” package I wrote something about this a while ago, there may meanwhile have been changes for compatibility, though: [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec).

But I can suggest an alternative: **`minitoc`**.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrwfile}

\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}
\mtcsetrules{parttoc}{off}
\mtcsettitle{parttoc}{Part Contents}
\mtcsettitlefont{parttoc}{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily} % "\sffamily" is KOMA-script default

\newcommand{\setparttoc}[1]{%
\mtcsetdepth{parttoc}{#1} % "0" as usual chapter depth
\parttoc
}

\begin{document}
\doparttoc

\mainmatter
\tableofcontents

\part{Part Heading First}
\setparttoc{0}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First section, again}

\part{Part Heading Second}
\setparttoc{1}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Another first section}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Why first sections only?}

\end{document}
```

Output of example in question (with `scrwfile` deactivated):

[image: output of example in question]

Output of example above in answer:

[image: output of example in answer]

This can surely be more fine tuned, but it shows the idea. Adding

```
\renewcommand*{\mtcgapbeforeheads}{-50pt}
\renewcommand*{\mtcgapafterheads}{-40pt}
```

will the appearance adapt more to the one from question. The values are by the way the opposite of the defaults for these part toc commands.

---

BTW for users, who know what they are doing: `scrwfile` prints out a warning into the log file claiming to be in Alpha state. This warning can be removed with the package `silence`.

Comment: I have not tested your example in my template yet, but I intentionally removed minitoc from the template a long time ago, though I can not remember the reasons. It may be related to the fact that it causes likely incompatibilities, is not maintained anymore (since 2008) and has a horrible interface...

Comment: Here is a post about minitoc being incompatible with titlesec, which I also use: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7182

Comment: That you use `titlesec` you did not mention … There are working packages with last changes before 2008 … What do you mean with interface? Do you mean: The documentation is far from ideal. I made two of my edits, because the recommended command is mentioned much later than the older one, especially on the places, where the older commands are explained often no hint to the newer version is given. (I am not a regular user user until now.) Otherwise there are worse documentations.